# Gap between the topbar and browser eventhough marigin : 0 auto?

Tags: html, css

I Do not need a Gap between the `topbar` and browser. But despite using the following css
code, am getting the gap between them.

```
   body 
       {
         font-size:14px;
         font-family:Arial;
       }
  .topbar
       {
         background-color:Black;
         width:70%;
         height:100px;
         margin:0 auto;
       }
```

Image of my sample topbar

[image: this is my sample topbar]

Comment: Could you post an image of the error?

Comment: i have added an image ..there is gap between browser bookmark bar and my sample topbar... how can i remove that gap b/w them?.  @HarshShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body element has margin by default

set

```
body
{
  margin:0;
}
```

and it should remove the gap.